# How to select variable name and surround it with ## using Atom

Tags: coldfusion, atom-editor

I have decided to jump from Sublime Text 3 to Atom. I deal with HTML,CSS,JS and *mostly* ColdFusion. I cant seem to figure out on Atom how to select a variable, say:

```
<cfoutput>testVariable</cfoutput>
```

and add surrounding `##` signs without Atom replacing the selected text with only `#`. The desired end result is:

```
<cfoutput>#testVariable#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: With Dreamweaver, it's ctrl-shift-3, or ctrl-#.  It's worth a shot,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is old, but just in case anyone else is looking, this worked for me:

In init.coffee:

```
wrapSelection = (selection, before, after) ->
  after ?= before
  selectedText = selection.getText()
  selection.insertText("#{before}#{selectedText}#{after}")

atom.commands.add 'atom-text-editor',
  'custom:wrap-with-pound', ->
     editor = @getModel()
     editor.transact ->
       wrapSelection(selection, "#", "#") for selection in editor.getSelections()
```

In keymap.cson:

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-#': 'custom:wrap-with-pound'
```

[image]